Does Bootstrap support building into a version with all properties defined by variables?
I want a version of Bootstrap, where all property values have corresponding variables.
For instance, the text-white utility should have --bs-text-color variable, equal to rgba(var(--bs-white-rgb), var(--bs-text-opacity)).
In the default built version text-white sets rgba(var(--bs-white-rgb), var(--bs-text-opacity)) directly to color.
Different classes should redefine the same variable. text-primary should set --bs-text-color to rgba(var(--bs-primary-rgb), var(--bs-text-opacity)).
I'd like to use the variables in my own classes, applied to Bootstrap-stylized controls, making them universal.
Can Bootstrap sources be built in a mode with intermediate variables? If so, what flags/settings/whatever should be used when compiling from SASS?
